# Mensaje personalizado para validación 'requiredIf' en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, validación

Estoy utilizando mensajes personalizados en una validación con Laravel, la mayoría me funcionan pero específicamente los que son **requiredIf** no me funcionan.

He visto que los utilizan así:

```
protected $mensajes = [
    'salas.required_if' => 'mensaje personalizado',
    'dormitorios.required_if' => 'mensaje personalizado'
]
```

pero a mi eso no me funciona. Aclaro que si toma el dato como obligatorio cuando se cumple la condición, pero no manda el mensaje que yo definí, manda uno que entiendo es predefinido:

**"El campo salas es obligatorio"**

**"El campo dormitorios es obligatorio"**

Mi condición es algo como esto:

```
$arreglo['salas'][] = Rule::requiredIf(function() use($request)
                          {
                               return $request->filled('dormitorios') ? false : true;
                          })

$arreglo['dormitorios'][] = Rule::requiredIf(function() use($request)
                          {
                               return $request->filled('salas') ? false : true;
                          })
```

Para dar un poco mas de contexto en cuanto a lo que quiero hacer, estoy recibiendo en un request dos arreglos (salas, dormitorios), pero quiero que siempre venga al menos uno de ellos o los dos, pero si ambos están ausentes estaría mal, y por eso la validación del **requiredIf**.

Comment: ¿En dónde haces la validación (controlador, FormRequest, validador personalizado, servicio) y en dónde defines el mensaje personalizado?

Comment: Todo en el controlador. Ya conseguí una solución, fíjate en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que conseguí fue colocar el mensaje para **required**, de esta forma:

```
protected $mensajes = [
    'salas.required' => 'mensaje personalizado',
    'dormitorios.required' => 'mensaje personalizado'
]
```

La validación la mantuve igual:

```
$arreglo['salas'][] = Rule::requiredIf(function() use($request)
                          {
                               return $request->filled('dormitorios') ? false : true;
                          })

$arreglo['dormitorios'][] = Rule::requiredIf(function() use($request)
                                {
                                     return $request->filled('salas') ? false : true;
                                })
```

De esa forma empezó a funcionar bien, la validación se sigue cumpliendo para 'salas' y 'dormitorios' pero esta vez el mensaje si es el que definí. Para mi este comportamiento tiene sentido ya que las validaciones **required** y **requiredIf** no tiene sentido que estén juntas ya que **required** tendría prioridad sobre **requiredIf**. Lo único que veo extraño es que Laravel por defecto ya trae mensajes para **required_if** en los archivos *validation.php* que se encuentran en el directorio *resources/lang*, pero ese mensaje nunca aparece , en su lugar siempre aparece el mensaje para **required** del mismo archivo.

El mensaje **"El campo :attribute es obligatorio"** que menciono en el planteamiento del problema, se encuentra en el archivo *resources/lang/es/validation.php*.